# object-fit: cover not working on Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a column of images of different sizes appear with equal height. I've read about `object-fit`. I can't seem to make it work though.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq9o8Lmc/)

Here's my current code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 p-0">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" data-wow-delay="0s" style="object-fit: cover !important; min-height: 100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="object-fit: cover !important; min-height: 100%"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I remove object-fit, there's no difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged your code. This will make sure the images doesn't get huge on browser resizing and images will be responsive as well.

[image]

```
<div class="col-4 p-0">
 <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
 <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" alt="" style="display: 
 block; 
 height: 100%; width: 100%;">
 </a>
</div>
```

This gives you a desired result since `object-fit` for some reason is not working (could be due to the aspect-ratio difference between the images.)

```html
<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-4 p-0">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4 p-0"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></a></div>
```

Comment: @bad boy: Let me know if it helped, do rate if it did. This will help other developers having the same issue that their problem solved.

Comment: this looks like it does the trick. I'll make tests and update this thread.

Thank you.

Comment: You are most Welcome, Do please vote, this encourages me to help more and more Front End Developers with Issues and gives me confidence also. Thank You Happy Coding :)

Comment: It almost, almost did the trick. The problem was when the images have significant differences in height, the other images become distorted just to cover the entire block/column. I added `object-fit: cover` in the image and it was perfect. Thank you for the help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed our first image was 600*400 and that's was giving some tough time :) You are most welcome ... Pleasure is all mine. :) Stay blessed...

Answer (score 0):

Position `absolute` for the parent container of the image made the magic

```
 <div class="col-4 p-0">
     <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;position: absolute;">
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" alt="" style="display: 
     block; 
     height: 100%; width: 100%;">
     </a>
    </div>
```